# RuntimeError: Could not locate app.query.rets.source_nodes[:].note.text in app/record

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to run trulens to evaluate the RAG triplet metric on my llama_index RAG.

My code:

```
from trulens_eval import TruLlama
from trulens_eval import FeedbackMode

tru_recoder = TruLlama(
    query_engine,
    app_id="App_1",
    feedbacks=[
        f_qa_relevance,
        f_qs_relevance,
        f_groundedness
    ]
)

with tru_recoder as recoding:
    query_engine.query("what are the key to building a career in AI?")
```

which throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 342, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\site-packages\trulens_eval\app.py", line 1168, in _add_future_feedback
    res = future_result.result()
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 451, in result
  return self.__get_result()
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\site-packages\trulens_eval\utils\python.py", line 374, in _future_target_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\site-packages\trulens_eval\utils\threading.py", line 174, in _run_with_timeout
    raise e
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\site-packages\trulens_eval\utils\threading.py", line 159, in _run_with_timeout
    res: T = fut.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 458, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
  raise self._exception
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\site-packages\trulens_eval\feedback\feedback.py", line 504, in run
    raise e
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\site-packages\trulens_eval\feedback\feedback.py", line 499, in run
    input_combinations = list(
  File "D:\software\anaconda3\envs\torch_py310\lib\site-packages\trulens_eval\feedback\feedback.py", line 710, in extract_selection
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Could not locate app.query.rets.source_nodes[:].note.text in app/record.
```

The RAG successfully runs the query but the metrics do not get computed. Any suggestions on how to fix?